# Wordpress - Resizing of large images is failing

Tags: php, wordpress, image, .htaccess, image-resizing

So I've been looking for a solution this problem for several days now and I've had no success.

I'm currently developing a site for Wordpress that utilizes high resolution images that are uploaded by users. For NDA reasons I can't disclose code or what the nature of the project is, so I'll be as descriptive as I can be with that in mind, though I know that can be difficult.

I'm having issues when uploading incredibly large images (6500x6500 pixels, or 3MB)+ when it comes to the Wordpress resizing of the image. Normally, with smaller images, Wordpress is able to resize these images that are uploaded into a variety of smaller sizes without a problem, but it seems at a certain point, either in file size or pixel dimensions, Wordpress is unable to perform this resizing.

When we upload an image, we're resizing it as many as 22 times (depending on user input and requirements). Maintaining the original image resolution is also really important for a later stage of the project so simply compressing or shrinking the original image isn't an option, either prior or during upload.

I've made changes to the .htaccess and php.ini file to allow for much larger file and upload sizes as well as execution times, but I suspect the issue is with an internal Wordpress function. Possibly add_image_size()?

I'll try to be as helpful as I can providing additional information that would help solve this.

Comment: Do you have access to the PHP error log? The image resize functions will emit warnings when an operation fails. Most commonly the PHP process exceeds memory limits when working with large images. You may need to increase the memory_limit, see here: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit

Comment: In memory, an uncompressed 6500x6500 RGB image would be ~127 MB.

Comment: Failing how?  What are the issues?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the quick response. Checking the logs did reveal that memory was being exceeded. After the comment from @gre_gor I increased the size of limit to a generous 512 MB, and the problem has vanished. Thanks for you help!

Comment: @Grinneh I added an answer, so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [increase the memory limit](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit). Big images can take a lot of memory.

An uncompressed 6500x6500 24bit RGB image would take ~127 MB of memory.